# Why does the compiler think Environment.Exit can return?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Example code:

```
switch(something)
{
    case 0:
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    case 1:
        // blah ...
        break;
}
```

It won't compile because the compiler thinks that execution can return from Exit(). The compiler is obviously wrong.

No tricks. `System.Environment.Exit()` is the real one.

Not only is it utterly illogical for `System.Environment.Exit()` to return, I traced the code and it eventually calls `ExitProcess(exitCode);` which can't return.

Comment: Since compiler can't look at method's IL to know what will be executed at run-time (because there is absolutely no way for compiler to know what exact assembly will be loaded at run-time), how would *you* propose compiler to know that given method does not ever return?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Given the current situation, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.NoReturn] void Exit(int ExitCode); If I were writing this anew there would be a type (similar to System.Void) that meant unreachable.

Comment: Attributes are not part of the method signature - so it would not work as compiler can't guarantee that at run-time library loaded to implement that method will even have the attribute (ignoring the fact that compiler and JIT will have to enforce behavior of that attribute somehow). Indeed return special type that is part of method signature would work, but would it worth to build whole extra infrastructure that validates that method can't return for this single special case of method that terminates process?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: function(out x) puts the lie to that. out is actually `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out]`. It's not quite so special purpose; any method guaranteed to throw could be tagged with this; also note that C and C++ have it. If calling a runtime library that's missing it the code wouldn't even load so that's a small problem.

Comment: Compiler just obey the [specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/statements.md#expression-statements): The end point of an *expression_statement* is reachable if that *expression_statement* is reachable.

Answer (score 6):

As far as the language is concerned, it can return.  Yes, in real-life the process will terminate before it has a chance to return, but the compiler doesn't know that based on the method signature.

You'll need to add the "break" in there to make the compiler happy.

Comment: It's hard to explain exactly what is wrong with this answer. It's almost like it's answering what rather than why.

Comment: Imagine you had a method called 'Foo' that called `System.Environment.Exit()`.  Would you expect the `switch` statement to enforce that you called `break` after calling `Foo()`, or would you expect the switch statement to understand the meaning of `Foo` by inspecting its code paths to know that it would terminate the process and couldn't ever return?

Comment: compilers shouldn't be dependent on the side effects of library calls.  This particular call is not guaranteed to work, It can throw an exception.

Comment: There was a time when I would have expected the compiler to figure it out in that case, but I have since learned that is a suboptimal choice and it should be part of the declaration.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: If it throws an exception it still doesn't fall through the case.